# CSS & JS: Overflow-y not working on DOM EL if overflow-x already set

Tags: javascript, css

I've walked into an dilema: I told my `body` Element to not scroll the x-axies: `overflow-x: hidden`.

Now i set the `overflow-y: hidden` on the `body` , when something is clicked with JavaScript. Now it look's like this, when inspection via DevTools:

[image]

Everything looks great, but i still am able to scroll the body. BUT when I remove the `overflow-x: hidden` styles from the DevTools the Body won't scroll anymore to the y-Axies?

[image]

How ist that possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do could u be more clear?

Comment: I think I got your problem but I still need to do some guessing. Can you post a code snippet so we can reproduce your problem and give you an answer with certainty?

Comment: @Leonardo I want the body to be non-scrollable, when a button is clicked. I'm adding the style `overflow-y: hidden` via javascript like this: `document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";`

Comment: does the body have a set height? It will need a set height for overflow hidden to work. Because how would it know from which point you want it hidden. full height of window would be 100vh for example

Comment: @JarneKompier ohh thanks a lot! This helped me achieve it. Wasn't thinking about this at all, but Totaly makes sence! Thank You.